# Initialization of class array

Tags: java

```
 class max{
     public int buy;
     public int sell;
     public max(int n){
         buy=0;
         sell=0;
     }
 }

public class MaxProfit{     
    public void stock(int a[],int n){
        max[] sol=new max[n/2+1];
        if(n==1||n==0)
        {
            return;
        }
    int i=0,count=0;
    while(i<n-1){
        while((i<n-1)&&(a[i+1]<=a[i]))
        i++;
        if(i==n-1)
        break;
        //System.out.println(sol[count].buy=i++);
        sol[count].buy=i++;
        i++;
        while((i<n)&&(a[i]>=a[i-1]))
        i++;
        sol[count].sell=i-1;
        count++;

    }
    for(int k=0;k<count;k++)
    System.out.println(sol[k].buy +sol[k].sell);


}

     public static void main(String []args){
         MaxProfit f=new MaxProfit();
        int arr[]={20,100,260};
        f.stock(arr,arr.length);

        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

A Exception is coming which is exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MaxProfit.stock(MaxProfit.java:15)
    at MaxProfit.main(MaxProfit.java:32)
I am not able to solve this I have initialized array of max still I am getting null pointer exception Please help

Comment: Are you purposefully removing the `{` and `}` after the while loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize the elements of `max[] sol` maybe in a loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<sol.length;i++){
   sol[i]=new max(aValue);
}
```

Comment: @user2665256 this code should be just below the max[] sol=new max[n/2+1]; and instead of aValue you should give an integer.

Comment: Ohh thnx got it thnku so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an array (`sol`) but you are not filling your array with objects `max`. before using your array fill it first. Just add this to initialize your array:

```
max[] sol=new max[n/2+1];

for(int i = 0; i < sol.length; i++) {
    sol[i] = new max(i /* or whatever the value that must be here */);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand this it is giving  illegal start of expression
sol[i] = new max(i);                                                        I want that sol[count].buy=i++ where count=0

Comment: try just this: `sol[i] = new max(i);`

Comment: Oh thnx got it.Thnx a tonne.

Answer (score 0):

```
max[] sol=new max[n/2+1];
```

just defines and array with no (null) contents. You must put valid `max` objects in it. Like

```
max[i] = new max(/*param*/);


sol[count].buy=i++;
```

is throwing the NPE

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void stock(int a[],int n){
   max[] sol=new max[n/2+1];
   if(n==1||n==0)
   {
        return;
   }
   for (int k = 0; k < sol.length; k++) {
       sol[k]= new max(k);
   }
   int i=0,count=0;
   while(i<n-1){
```